# python loop over subprocess.check_output by line

Tags: python-2.7, subprocess

I need to loop over the output of a command. I thought I'd use `subprocess.check_output`, now I have two problems.

Here's a file:

```
foo
bar
```

Here's my python script:

```
import subprocess

for line in subprocess.check_output(['cat', 'foo']):
  print "%r" % line
```

And here's what I get:

```
$ python subp.py 
'f'
'o'
'o'
'\n'
'b'
'a'
'r'
'\n'
```

I expect:

```
$ python subp.py
'foo\n'
'bar\n'
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

subprocess.check_output(['cat', 'foo']) returns a string: "foo\nbar"

Thus, your for loop iterates over the string, printing every character, one-by-one.

The following should fix your problem:

```
import subprocess

print subprocess.check_output(['cat', 'foo'])
```

You can also do:

```
import subprocess

for line in subprocess.check_output(['cat', 'foo']).split('\n'):
    print "%r" % line
```

Comment: Could also use [`.splitlines()`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) or `p = `[`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor)`(..., stdout=subprocess.PIPE);for line in p.stdout: ...`

Comment: When I run this on `git ls-files`, the last line is empty (because `git ls-files` ends its output on a newline). So I need to add something like `if line != '':`. Is there a more elegant way without an additional `if`? Edit: Got it: `rstrip('\n')` before the `split('\n')`

Answer (score 13):

With Python3 previous answer doesn't work immediately, because `bytes` are returned by `check_output`

Then you can either decode bytes into a string or split them immediately:

```
output = subprocess.check_output(['cat', 'foo'])

# splitting with byte-string
for line in output.split(b'\n'): 
    print(line)

# or decoding output to usual string
output_str = output.decode()
for line in output_str.split('\n'):
    print(line)
```

Comment: If you are going to process text (the typical use), adding `text=True` (or, if the text is not UTF-8, `encoding=whatever`) is the better solution.

Answer (score 2):

Python3:

```
for line in subprocess.check_output(['cat', 'foo'], universal_newlines=True).split('\n'):
    print(line)
```