# Python shell output as separate lines

Tags: python, list

I am new to python, and need some help.
This is my code:

```
import subprocess

direct_output = subprocess.check_output('find / -type f -name \"*.srt\"', shell=True)
print direct_output
```

I have output like this:

```
/path/to/my/code/name.srt

/path/to/my/code/other_name.srt
```

But I want to list this outputs one by one. Something like:
`print print direct_output[1]`

output:

```
/path/to/my/code/other_name.srt
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python loop over subprocess.check\_output by line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18244091/python-loop-over-subprocess-check-output-by-line)

Comment: Why are you not using a python function (glob?) for this task? Do you really want a different process?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find all files in a directory with extension .txt in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964681/find-all-files-in-a-directory-with-extension-txt-in-python)

Comment: Read http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/lists/python-lists-cheat-sheet